# Ошибка при установке apk dynamic feature module

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-gradle

Я добавил dynamic feature module в свое приложение. Собрал две apk

> Build -> Build bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)

одна для модуля `:app`, вторая для модуля `:dynamicFeature`. Установил apk для модуля :app, затем, при попытке установки apk для модуля `:dynamicFeature`, появляется ошибка `The APK failed to install. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Full install must include a base package`

При попытке установки на устройство нажатием кнопки `Run` [image: введите сюда описание изображения] оба модуля устанавливаются корректно и запускаются. Что делать с этой ошибкой?

**build.gradle(Module :app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.dynamicfeatureapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    dynamicFeatures = [':dynamicfeature']
}

dependencies {...}
```

**build.gradle(Module :dynamicFeature)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dynamicfeature"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":app")
    ...
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml(Module :dynamicFeature)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.dynamicfeature">

    <dist:module
        dist:instant="false"
        dist:title="@string/title_dynamic_feature">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:on-demand />
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="false" />
    </dist:module>

</manifest>
```

В файле gradle.properties включен

```
android.experimental.enableNewResourceShrinker
```